# how to use sed to extract lines in specified order?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a file which is ~50,000 lines long , and I need to retrieve specific lines. I have tried the following command :

```
sed -n 'Np;Np;Np' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
```

( 'N' being the specific lines, I want to extract )

This works fine, but the command extracts the lines in ORDER (i.e. it RE-ORDERS my input) ex. if I try:

```
sed -n '200p;33p;40,000p' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
```

I get a text file with the lines ordered as: 33, 200, 40,000 (which doesn't work for my purpose). Is there a way to maintain the order in which lines appear in the command?

Answer (score 14):

You have to hold on to line 33 until after you've seen line 200:

```
sed -n '33h; 200{p; g; p}; 40000p' file
```

See the manual for further explanation: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html

`awk` might be more readable:

```
awk '
    NR == 33    {line33 = $0} 
    NR == 200   {print; print line33} 
    NR == 40000 {print}
' file
```

If you have an arbitrary number of lines to print in a specific order, you can generalize this:

```
awk -v line_order="11 3 5 1" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(line_order, inorder)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) linenums[inorder[i]]
    }
    NR in linenums {cache[NR]=$0}
    END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print cache[inorder[i]]}
' file
```

Comment: I tested sed and the first awk solutions, but line 33 prints empty line. last awk solition runs correctly.

Answer (score 4):

with `perl`, saves input lines in hash variable with line number as key

```
$ seq 12 20 | perl -nle '
@l = (5,2,3,1);
$a{$.} = $_ if( grep { $_ == $. } @l );
END { print $a{$_} foreach @l } '
16
13
14
12
```

- `$.` is line number and `grep { $_ == $. } @l` checks if that line number is present in the array `@l` which contains desired lines in order required

as a one-liner, `@l` declaration inside `BEGIN` to avoid initialization every iteration and also ensuring no blank lines if line number is out of range:

```
$ seq 50000 > inputFile.txt
$ perl -nle 'BEGIN{@l=(200,33,40000)} $a{$.}=$_ if(grep {$_ == $.} @l); END { $a{$_} and print $a{$_} foreach (@l) }' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
$ cat outputFile.txt
200
33
40000
```

For small enough input, can save the lines in an array and print indexes required. Note the adjustment made as index starts with `0`

```
$ seq 50000 | perl -e '$l[0]=0; push @l,<>; print @l[200,33,40000]'
200
33
40000
```

Solution with `head` and `tail` combo:

```
$ for i in 200 33 40000; do head -"${i}" inputFile.txt | tail -1 ; done
200
33
40000
```

**Performance comparison** for input file `seq 50000 > inputFile.txt`

```
$ time perl -nle 'BEGIN{@l=(200,33,40000)} $a{$.}=$_ if(grep {$_ == $.} @l); END { $a{$_} and print $a{$_} foreach (@l) }' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time awk -v line_order="200 33 40000" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(line_order, inorder)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) linenums[inorder[i]]
    }
    NR in linenums {cache[NR]=$0}
    END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print cache[inorder[i]]}
' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time for i in 200 33 40000; do sed -n "${i}{p;q}" inputFile.txt ; done > outputFile.txt

real    0m0.011s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time sed -n '33h; 200{p; g; p}; 40000p' inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time for i in 200 33 40000; do head -"${i}" inputFile.txt | tail -1 ; done > outputFile.txt

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you use also other bash commands? In that case this works:

```
for i in 200 33 40000; do 
    sed -n "${i}p" inputFile.txt
done > outputFile.txt
```

Probably this is slower than using array within sed, but it is more practical.

Comment: If you're going to parse the file multiple times,then at least quit after printing the wanted line: `sed -n "${i} {p;q}"`